# Задание CSS параметра через Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css

Есть такой скриптик:

```
var lamp = document.getElementById('lamp_form');
function lamp_form(){
    if(lamp.style.display=='block')
        lamp.style.display='none';
    else
        lamp.style.display='block';
    return false;   
}
```

Который выполняется при событии - клик.
Этот скрипт выполняется хорошо, но если в нем изменить строку допустим так:

```
var lamp = document.getElementById('lamp_form');
function lamp_form(){
    if(lamp.style.display=='block')
        lamp.style.background-position='-100px -100px';
    else
        lamp.style.display='block';
    return false;   
}
```

То эта строка не выполняется. Почему Js не хочет менять параметр background-position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что параметры, имеющие штрих, вводятся через `camlCase`, т.е. `backgroundPosition`.

Comment: Моя большая благодарность.